# when i refresh my page it send empty fields to database. my code is as follows

Tags: php, mysql

I created php form for inserting data to mysql. Data is inserted successfully but when i refresh my page it send empty fields to mysql db. code is as follows..

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("connection fail");
mysqli_select_db($con, 'college') or die ("database error");


$n=$_POST["name"];
$c=$_POST["class"];

$sql="insert into studentsinfo(name,class) values('$n','$c')";

mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "1 record inserted";
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>


<body>

 <form action="" method="post">

Name: <input type="text" name="name" required="required" title="Enter Name">
Class: <input type="text" name="class" required="required">
<input type="submit" value="insert" name="sub">
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

any suggestion please.

Comment: Widely open to sql injection, No validation, Open to XSS, No redirect after successfully form insert data. and pondering over on **why inserting blank values**

Comment: What do you mean by "when you refresh"? Is it after you post the data to the database successfully you then refresh the page then it performs another POST with empty fields?

Comment: i mean when i refresh in browser or open my page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have your php and html code on same page. first php code get executed. this is why you get empty row inserted in data base on every time you refresh.

Solution is use different page for logic or check condition when submit button is pressed by using isset() and empty() function in php.
Also add condition in data base that they can not be blank.

Answer (score 0):

> Just need to check form request is empty or not

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("connection fail");
mysqli_select_db($con, 'college') or die ("database error");

if(isset($_REQUEST['sub']))
{

$n=$_POST["name"];
$c=$_POST["class"];

$sql="insert into studentsinfo(name,class) values('$n','$c')";

mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo "1 record inserted";
}
?>

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
<body>

 <form action="" method="post">

Name: <input type="text" name="name" required="required" title="Enter Name">
Class: <input type="text" name="class" required="required">
<input type="submit" value="insert" name="sub">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Also  Use Prepared Statements to prevent SQL injections**

```
    if (isset($_POST['sub'])) {
      $n=$_POST["name"];
      $c=$_POST["class"];

      $sql="insert into studentsinfo(name,class) values('$n','$c')";

      mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      echo "1 record inserted";
    }
```